# How to cast a field to a datatype when inserting

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Hi I am trying to insert json in a postgresql database. A field is being inserted as a string but I'd like to cast it as an INT. Here is the code:

```
INSERT INTO z23 (id, data) values (DEFAULT, '{"test": "2"::int}')
```

As you can see `::int` does not work. Is there a way to do this inside the json?

Comment: Can't you just fix the JSON before it gets to the database?

Comment: can show you `z23` structure ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO z23 (id, data) values (DEFAULT, '{"test": 2}')
```